# Add custom JavaScript to SharePoint 2013 list

Tags: 2013, list, javascript

I need to add a custom JavaScript link to my SharePoint list, so it would only affect that list. I don't need to add it to any other forms. How could it be done?

I was thinking, if to change .aspx file, where the list sits (if it is possible), if this is a good idea, then where can I find that file?

EDIT: I need this to pin my top row (column names) to top of browser view, so I wouldn't lose them, when user scrolls to bottom of page.

Comment: Why do you need that? This could help to brind you an answer.

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: JSLink or adding a script editor on the views .aspx page are good ways for doing this

Comment: How to I add script editor to my view in list. When I try it through designer, then it won't change anything

Comment: if you want to change the display of the data, you surely want check CSR _Client-Side Rendering_, see this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do as follows from the browser:

- Edit the list page from top right gear/edit page
- Add new web part/Script Editor to the page
- Add your javascript code

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks! Forgot to look for edit page from there at all..

Answer (score 3):

I usually use either a script editor web part or a content editor web part.

If you want to create sticky headers in a SharePoint list, I've been using the below library and have been pretty happy with the results.

http://spoodoo.com/sticky-headers-in-sharepoint-2013/

All you have to do to implement is throw a copy of the sticky headers js file and a copy of jQuery in a script editor above the list view and you'll magically have a fixed header when you scroll the list view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was looking at the same solution! :)

Answer (score 3):

The "CEWP" approach is Ok. But you need to remember that EVERY LIST VIEW creates a "new" .aspx page.

So, "AllItems.aspx", will receive a CEWP with you JS. Your list have a "MyItens.aspx" view? Another CEWP.

Be aware of this point and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

1) Edit the page of the view

2) Add a Content Editor Web Part

3) Link this CEWP to a file containing JavaScript and CSS

4) Store this file in a SharePoint Document Library

Sample: https://ybbest.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/how-to-use-html-and-javascript-in-content-editor-web-part-in-sharepoint2010/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, forgot about edit page under gear symbol

Comment: Steps 3 and 4 are very importante to separate the code and easy editing.

Answer (score 0):

Given the response William — use C# job to programmaticaly get all list views and add CEWP for each. CEWP must reference your javascript file.